# Code's write either 1 line too many, or 1 line short of what's it supposed to write

Tags: vb.net, streamreader, streamwriter

I recently coded an app which creates a random password out of characters taken from the alphabet, then encrypt them using the Rijndael algorithm and writes them to a .txt file.

Call me paranoid, but I like password security.

Now today, I ran into a problem, it was all working just fine, until just now.

I wanted to create a new password and have it added to my initial file, which already contained another password and my access key.

For some reason, the code below either appends the new text to the previous line, which messes up my decryption, or (using the commented code) it inserts a blank line in between the previous line and the one it had just written.

```
Dim empty As Boolean = True
Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(fileLoc)
    'If Not reader.ReadLine() Is Nothing Then
    '    empty = False
    'End If
End Using

Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fileLoc, True)
    If Not empty Then
        writer.WriteLine()
    End If
    If passName = "" Then
        writer.WriteLine(cryptPass)
    Else
        writer.WriteLine(passName & " " & cryptPass)
    End If
End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this out instead:

```
    Dim lines As New List(Of String)
    lines.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileLoc))
    For i As Integer = lines.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If lines(i) = "" Then
            lines.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
    Next

    If passName = "" Then
        lines.Add(cryptPass)
    Else
        lines.Add(passName & " " & cryptPass)
    End If

    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(fileLoc, lines.ToArray)
```

Comment: Just making sure I've got this right, since it's pretty late, you think it's best to just rewrite all the lines in the file before adding the new line? As the file grows when more passwords are added, won't that choke up at a certain point?

Comment: If the file gets really big then, yes, it will not make sense to rewrite the entire thing each time if you only want to add a new line.  Did you have different versions of the file writing code at one point?  This might have caused the inconsistency.  The code I posted will reset the file and make it consistent.  Once that is done you could use different code to write just a new line to the end.